# Laravel Ajax and Session issue?

Tags: php, ajax, session, laravel

I have an ajax call which fires right when the DOM has finished loading, yet I am trying to prevent a situation when the user hits refresh and fires that ajax call again by storing a session variable.
Yet, there seems to be an issue with storing a session entry via AJAX request, consider the following snippet:

```
<?php
function postMyAjax() {

$already_fired = \Session::get('ajax_fired'); // <-- Always returns NULL!
if ( ! empty( $already_fired ) ) {
    return Response::json(array('already fired'));
}

# Remember that we fired that call
\Session::put('ajax_fired',1); // <-- Fails to set?

return Response::json(array('ok'));

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not set the value in a cookie after the first request is fired and check for it in your JS?

Comment: That's another good option, but that doesn't solve my session issue ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of answering the question, this has been a bug since laravel 4.1 where session handling becomes unstable with asynchronous requests.It is intensively being discussed here in github [issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172). My research points to the fact that basically, Laravel saves sessions in the last part of the request cycle and ajax/asynchronous requests processes differently as opposed to requests from browsers.